# Start Spring Boot app with Spring Integration Kafka consumers paused

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-integration

I am working on a Spring Boot application that uses Spring Integration flows that have Kafka topics as their source. Our integration flow starts using an interface containing SubscribableChannels with springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input and Output annotations. These are configured to read from Kafka via Cloud Config with spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.

When the app first starts up it immediately begins reading from the Kafka topics. This is a problem as the app needs to initialize some local, non-persistable databases before it can start correctly processing incoming Kafka messages.

We are currently using a @PostConstruct to populate these in-memory databases before Kafka starts but this is suboptimal as the app can't use Eureka, Feign, etc, to reliably find a healthy service that has the latest data for the in-memory database.

For a variety of reasons the architecture can't be changed such that the in-memory database is shared  or prepopulated. Just know that when I call it an in-memory database I'm simplifying things a bit, it's actually another service, of sorts.

What is the best way to start a Spring Boot app such that an Integration Flow that reads from Kafka starts in a paused state and can be unpaused after some other process completes?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` and according your mentioning of Spring Integration Java DSL - `Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()` to be exact. That one can be configured with the `id` and `autoStartup(false)`. Therefore it isn't going to start to consume Kafka topic immediately. Whenever you are ready to consume, you can `start()` this component obtaining it as a `Lifecycle` from the application context using the mentioned id.

Or you can send an appropriate message to the [Control Bus](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#control-bus).

**UPDATE**

If you deal with Spring Cloud Stream and Kafka Binder, you should consider to inject a `BindingsEndpoint` bean and perform its `changeState(@Selector String name, State state)` for the name of your binding and the `State.STOPPED`. When your in-memory DB is ready you call it back with the `State.STARTED`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_binding_visualization_and_control

Comment: I can't recall seeing those classes. I've edited my question with more details about how the Kafka topic is connected to the integration flow.

Comment: Oh! That's different story. You had to share the code with us. With the current state you are misleading us. There is definitely an `IntegrationFlow` abstraction. That's why I'm confused: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/java-dsl.html

Comment: @TomatoCo Was just discussing it with Artem. . . At the moment we do not have this feature in spring cloud stream, which is what I assume you are using. If so, I'd suggest to also raise the issue [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues) so we can address it.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.